# Как правильно работать со SteamAPI?

Tags: golang

Здравствуйте.
Есть потребность в авторизации через Steam. Я так понял что нужно использовать OpenID, зарегистрировал его тут "http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey" и не понимаю что дальше.
Мне бы очень хотелось узнать, как правильно работать со SteamAPI, как делать и обрабатывать запросы.
Буду признателен любой информации.

Comment: https://golanglibs.com/top?q=steam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самого щас заинтересовало, вообще api совсем простое, вот примеры на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/172223/

к примеру получить информацию о пользователе довольно просто. Достаточно лишь ввести в адресную строку браузера запрос в виде:

```
steamcommunity.com/profiles*SteamID*/?xml=1
```

можно даже курлом запросить и отловить далее обработывать в виде xml...

Comment: Вы случайно не делали авторизацию через openid steam?